# Que signifie « là-dessus »?

Tags: expressions, vocabulaire

Après une petite discussion sur un projet, une personne de mon équipe m'a dit:

*"**Là-dessus**, je vais modifier le serveur".*

Que signifie l'expression « là-dessus » dans cet exemple? Est-ce qu'il y a d'autres significations pour cette expression?

Comment: Oui. Parce que ça ne fait pas du sens pour moi. Quand il dit: "Je vais modifier là-dessus", je pensait qu'il voulait dire "je vais faire un changement là". Mais maintenant, je ne suis pas sur. Je voudrais comprend si "là-dessus" a un sens de localisation, comme "là-bas", ou bien non. Je vous demande pardon se ma question n'est pas bien faite, mais ma langue maternelle n'est pas le français.

Comment: Effectivement je t'avais pris pour un francophone... Non ta question est très bien posée.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Là-dessus** peut avoir trois sens différents.

**1.** Peut servir à localiser quelque chose :

> Mettez vos affaires là-dessus.

(*là* représentant un objet qu'on peut voir quand on dit la phrase)

**2.** Peut désigner une idée dont on vient de parler :

> Je t'appellerai demain, tu peux compter là-dessus.

On pourrait remplacer *là-dessus* par *sur ça* dans cette phrase.

**3.** Peut jouer le rôle d'un adverbe de temps, il signifie alors, *maintenant*, *quand (j'aurai) fini (de parler)*. C'est le sens qu'a cette expression dans la phrase que tu donnes.
Une expression synonyme dans ce sens serait *sur ce*.

Du style normal au style le plus soutenu les phrases suivantes sont synonymes :

> Maintenant je vais modifier le serveur.
> Là-dessus, je vais modifier le serveur.
> Sur ce, je vais modifier le serveur.

Dans les sens 1 et 2 *là-dessus* est en général placé en fin de phrase et dans le sens 3 en début de phrase. Dans certains contextes la place est déterminante pour comprendre.

« Je vais mettre mon manteau là-dessus. » veut dire : « Je vais poser mon manteau sur (cet objet). »

« Là-dessus, je vais mettre mon manteau. » veut dire : « Sur ce, je vais mettre mon manteau. » (Ce qui probablement sous-entend que je vais partir.)

Maintenant tu devrais pouvoir retrouver le sens dans ta langue maternelle dans un dictionnaire.

Answer (score 5):

Je pense qu'ici, cette expression peut être remplacée par « alors » ou « maintenant ».

Answer (score -1):

**Sens 1**

Là-dessus signifie aussitôt, en ce moment, à ce point, sur la réalité de telle ou telle chose.
Exemple : Là-dessus, il partit sans ménagement et sans se retourner.

**Sens 2**

Sur quelque chose, sur cela.
Exemple : Rangez l'ensemble de vos affaires là-dessus pour ne pas

Comment: En quoi cette réponse est-elle meilleure que celle qui a été acceptée ?